# starting, stopping and restarting windows services using node js

Tags: node.js, windows, service

Can someone explain how I can start or stop a windows service using a node program? Not a NodeJS service running on Windows, but specifically a Windows service itself, and that too, using NODEJS. There are lots of articles as to how to kill or start a NodeJS service, but not of what I am in need of here. There is an article though on StackOverflow in the following link:

[Node js start and stop windows services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726759/node-js-start-and-stop-windows-services)

But I am either not doing it right because I have not understood it the way it should be or it doesn't do what I need it to do. Please help me out. Don't know why, but there are just almost no articles online about this.

Answer (score 1):

**USE `os-services` module**

```
npm install os-service
It is loaded using the require() function:

var service = require ("os-service");
A program can then be added, removed and run as a service:

service.add ("my-service");

service.remove ("my-service");

service.run (function () {
    // Stop request received (i.e. a kill signal on Linux or from the
    // Service Control Manager on Windows), so let's stop!
    service.stop ();
});
```

Comment: no Waqar.. Didn't work. Thanks for the help anyway buddy.

Comment: what do you get any error? please post the error so that we can further resolve it.

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer when OP says it don't solve the problem? Does it work or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use bat file to stop and start node server or user nodemon package.
And use windows task scheduler

```
@echo off
cd "D:\sam\Projects\NodeSchedule // path of node project i.e. index.js
taskkill /IM node.exe -F
start /min cmd /C "node index.js"
goto :EOF
```